# Xcode.IDEInterfaceBuilder.Cocoa.NSContainerView.RepeatingSeparationInParentChain

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode-storyboard

Here's a new one.  I have a storyboard that includes a container view.  I just added another container view within a view (that has no segue to any other), but I get a somewhat cryptic compiler error:

```
Xcode.IDEInterfaceBuilder.Cocoa.NSContainerView.RepeatingSeparationInParentChain
```

Has anyone seen this before?  Removing the second container view eliminates the error, but I'd really like to use it.